# Find the matrix $A$ of transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the matrix $A$ of the transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2$ given below.$$T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-7x-5y+7z\\ 2x+7y+6z\end{bmatrix}$$

Hi. I just don't know how to solve this problem. 
It doesn't look that hard question, but I just don't understand what I have to get.

Thank you very much if you can help me with how to process and answer.

Comment: Here's a hint. What must be the dimensions of the matrix T in order for the matrix multiplication to make sense?

Comment: The first column of the matrix $A$ is the image of $e_1$, the second is the image of $e_2$, the third is the image of $e_3$.

Comment: [This video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE), while only talking about linear transformations $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$, explains pretty well what such a matrix looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a unique answer to your question, in other words, different many matrices could be rappresent a linear transformation. But when you fix the basis, then the matrix become unique. Different choice of basis gives different matrix.

In your case: choose the standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$, $\Bbb R^2$; thus the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}-7&-5&7\\ 2&7&6\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It would be good if you explained how you arrived at this answer, since that’s what the OP is asking about.